# how to include file in zend framework controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework

hello I am newbie in zend framework ..

I want to know how to includes files in zend framework Controller

I am using action in zend framework controller like that

```
public function anyAction()
{
   require("../mailchimp/anyfile.php");
}
```

what I can do to include this files, means where is the right place to kept all this files

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what the `library` directory is typically used for.  You can put your own functions in there as well as any 3rd party code.  Some even put the ZF library in there, but I tend to keep ZF elsewhere on the server and add it to the include_path in `php.ini`.

With the mailchimp files in your `library` folder, you can include them like this:

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/mailchimp/MCAPI.class.php';
```

If you add `library` to your path, then you could shorten it to just:

```
require_once 'mailchimp/MCAPI.class.php';
```

You can add library to your path by adding `includePaths.library = APPLICATION_PATH "/../library"` to your `application.ini` file.  Just be aware of the possible [performance penalty](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html#performance.classloading.includepath) you may take by adding additional locations to your include_path.

EDIT:

To display an image that you have stored in `public/images`, you would use this call from your view/layout:

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->baseUrl('images/file.jpg') ?>" alt="file.jpg" />
```

This takes care of figuring out what your base URL is in the event that your Zend Application is not in the root directory of your domain.  See the [BaseUrl View Helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial.baseurl) for more info.

Comment: :) and also may i know how to include images inside any phtml page ???? means how to give the link, I placed my images folder inside public directory.

Answer (score -2):

In Zend-Framework you must follow MVC pattern to create any page. when you want to use/call this page you write url using module, controller and action like bellow:

> require($this->url(array('module'=>'default','controller'=>'mailchimp','action'=>'mailchimp')));