# zend framework include php array in controller

Tags: php, zend-framework

A simple question that i cant resolve, how can i include a php file (with array) in the controler. When is place the file in src (not the good place, but for the example), the file is not found

```
$kenmerken = include('../src/1_vakantie-en-recreatie.php');
```

Comment: Have you tried with absolute server path?

Comment: How does that look like?

Comment: `'/var/www/project-directory/path/to/src/1_vakantie-en-recreatie.php'` in example.

Answer (score 1):

I think your answer is here: 
[how to include file in zend framework controller?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594588/how-to-include-file-in-zend-framework-controller)

If this didn't solved your problem let me know.
good luck!

Comment: Not working (bacause of old version of ZF in that question i think)

Comment: Try using this absolute path:  

`$paths = array(
    realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '/../library'),
    '.',
);
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, $paths);`  

source: https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.11/en/performance.classloading.html  

If you still have the same problem please give us more info about the error you're having and the version you are using.